# Display textbox value post selecting a value from dropdownlist(should display amount of the product post selecting the product from the dropdown)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

**table**
p_id  p_name            p_amount
1    Telephone bill         500
2    Groceries              1000
3    Toiletries             800
4    Gym                    1500
5    Alcohol                1800
6    Clothing               5000
7    Movie                  500

'''
**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Product_Det()             
    {
        Product_det Name = new Product_det();
        Name.ProductName = ProductName();
        return View(Name);
    }
      public JsonResult selectSBU(string id) 
    {
        List<Product_det> branches = PopulateBranches();
        return Json(branches.Where(x => x.p_id == id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Method for textbox(p_amount)**

```
    private List<Product_det> PopulateBranches()
    {
        List<Product_det> items = new List<Product_det>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localdb"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "select p_amount from tbl_product";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                var employee = new Product_det();
                employee.p_amount = sdr["p_amount"].ToString();
                
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

**Method for dropdown(p_name)**

```
    private static List<SelectListItem> ProductName()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localdb"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = " select * from tbl_product";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = sdr["p_name"].ToString(),

                            Value = sdr["p_id"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

**View**

```
  @model Expense_Tracker.Models.Product_det
  @{

    Layout = null;
}

<div id="main-div">
    <div id="box" class="img-responsive">
        @using (@Html.BeginForm())
            {
            <div class="insidebox">
                <div> <h1>Product & Amount</h1></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>

                        @Html.DropDownList("p_name", new SelectList(ViewBag.Product_det, "p_name", "p_name"), "Select Product", new { @id = "ddlProduct_det", @class = "SelectCtrlGHN", onchange = "return get_sbu(this)" })
                        <label class="FieldGH">Price</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtp_amount" name="GrpHead" value="" readonly class="PO_GH" />

                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function get_sbu() {
                        var selected_val = $('#ddlProduct_det').find(":selected").attr('value');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Expense/selectSBU",
                            data: "id=" + selected_val,
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.length > 0) {
                                    $('#txtp_amount').val(data[0].p_amount);
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('#txtp_amount').val('');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                </script>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success btn-block" />

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <p style="color:red">@ViewBag.error</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

'''

Comment: Hello Rana, what is your question? Also, this looks like a test question, we cannot provide answers for those.

Comment: It's not a test question, I am trying to display the cost of a item, based on the selection of product from Drop down, Ex- if i select GYM it's price(text) 1500 should be displayed.

Comment: You look like you have everything. Put a break point in the success statement. I'm suspecting it's not hitting your controller, instead of using the data attribute, add it to the url, `url: "/Expense/selectSBU?id=" + selected_val`